# How to find a cylinders axis from points on the surface.

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to find the axis of a cylinder with a known diameter in 3D space from points on its surface?

I would guess that at least 3 points would be required.

Comment: Not if the points were colinear.

Comment: I assume you refer to a right circular cylinder. With 3 non-collinear points a circum-circle can be made which lies in a plane perpendicular to cylinder axis. With 5 collinear points a conic can be made. If it is an ellipse then $\cos^{-1}(b/a) $ is its inclination to cylinder axis

Answer (score 0):

These references concern the same question but without a known diameter.

(1) Perhaps take a look at [NLREG](http://www.nlreg.com/cylinder.jpg):

> Cylindrical Regression—Fit a Cylinder to Data Points
>
> ---
>
> [image]

---

(2) See "Cylinders Through Five Points: Computational Algebra and
Geometry" ([PDF download](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7521/cylinder_5_points_computation.pdf)), by Daniel Lichtblau, for theoretical background
and Mathematica code.

Comment: Your link doesn't appear to take into account that the diameter is known.

Comment: @Jens: You are correct; thanks. I will so indicate.